# MySQL Master <-> Slave, PDO , Zend Framework and Transactions

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

We have some wired problems with the following structure:

- Zend Framework 1
- MySQL 5 Master <-> Slave replication
- PDO (Zend) Transactions

Example:

Query 1

```
 $adapter->beginTransaction():      
 $where = $adapter->quoteInto('ID = ?', $id);
 $adapter->update()...
 $adapter->commit();
```

Query 2

```
 $adapter->beginTransaction():      
 $where = $adapter->quoteInto('ID = ?', $id);
 $adapter->update()...
 $adapter->commit();
```

When started on an non cluster mysql server everything works fine. When started on an replicated enviorment we get the following exception:

There is no active transaction

Now i have added:

```
$adapter->closeConnection();
```

after the first query, voila it works on the cluster. Removed it : and it is still working...

Cant explain this, maybe an unclosed transaction? or normal behavoir?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a plugin that ensures that the connections are closed on every http request? I used to have weird behaviors with zend and dbs because the connections were remaining open.

Comment: There is no plugin, but i think it must be some problem with Zend in combination with mySQL Cluster... think there is no solution